# How to add a scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I have hidden menus and submenus, if I open all my hidden submenus. I don't know how to see the last menu, because I don't have a scroll bar.

How to add a scrollbar?

Here is my project -> [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pnrecf?file=src/styles.css)

Comment: Add `overflow-y: scroll;` to `.sidebar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean like this. Try this code

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 330px;
  background: #0a2558;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;
}
```